# Find Cartesian equation from Parametric Equations Including Sec and Tan

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, parametric

Need to find the cartesian equation from:

$$ x = sec^2t - 1 , y = tan t, -\frac\pi2 \lt t \lt \frac \pi2 $$

With sin and cosine I use the unit circle, but I don't know what to do with sec and tangent. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : 
$$\tan^2 t + 1 = \sec^2 t$$

Comment: I totally forgot about that identity... that gives me $ y = +- \sqrt x $ ... which is $ x = y^2   $ which is what is in the back of the book, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\sec(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$
$$\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$$

Comment: That's what I tried, and I ended up with $  y = xsint $  when it should be $ y = x^2 $ if I am not mistaken from looking at the back of my book

Comment: How did you solve for cos and sin, could you show me what you did?

Comment: Woops, the answer is $x = y^2$, I forgot about the tangent identity in the other answer